# retrieving identical rows of some columns from a list

Tags: c#, list

I am working on a `C# list` of type that I defined myself which has about 7 columns and several rows of data and I am trying to retrieve data of three columns which has same data in it.

For Example my C# list has following data

```
Time    Code Range  Unit   Type   Price Volume 
8:13:43 LN  N15-U15 300     Put   0.1   250
8:13:53 LN  N15-U15 300     Put   0.1   50
8:14:01 LN  N15-U15 300     Put   0.099 100
8:14:08 LN  N15-U15 300     Put   0.099 50
8:16:49 LN  V14     380/400 Call  0.063 50
8:17:04 LN  V14     380/400 Call  0.001 50
8:18:43 LN  N15-U15 450     Call  0.125 50
8:34:00 LN  F15      500    Call  0.053 200
```

From the above Data I want to retrieve one row for each similar `Code,Range, Unit and Type` and store it another `C# list`
So, I want the new list of four columns to be as follows

```
Code Range  Unit   Type  Repeated
LN  N15-U15 300     Put  4 times
LN  V14     380/400 Call 2 times
```

The above two rows are the only rows with similar `Code,Range, Unit and Type`

I am trying to loop through the list and retrieve using the following

```
                int i=1;
                foreach (var row in listStructures)
                {
                    if (listStructures[i - 1].Code == listStructures[i].Code 
                        && listStructures[i - 1].Range== listStructures[i].Range
                        && listStructures[i - 1].Unit== listStructures[i].Unit
                        && listStructures[i - 1].Type== listStructures[i].Type)
                    {
                        //perform operations on the list
                    }
                    i++;
                }
```

The above code obviously is not efficient as it just compares only two rows at a time and doesn't give me the desired results.

**Is there a better way I can solve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq is your friend:

```
var result = from row in listStructures 
             group row by new {row.Code, row.Range, Row.Unit, Row.Type} into grp
             let Item = grp.Key
             select new {Code=Item.Code, Range=Item.Range, Unit=Item.Unit, Type=Item.Type, Repeated=grp.Count()}
```

Thanks to michael moore for his correction.

Comment: Why do you use `let Item = grp.First()` instead of using `grp.Key....` directly? 
`from row in listStructures 
 group row by new {row.Code, row.Range, Row.Unit, Row.Type} into grp
 select new {Code=grp.Key.Code, Range=grp.Key.Range, ... Repeated=grp.Count() }`